# Theorem 4-13 Spivak's Stokes Theorem

Tags: manifolds, differential-forms, stokes-theorem

This is a question regarding the first part of Spivak's proof of Stokes' theorem. Let $\omega$ be a $(k-1)$-form on $[0,1]^k$. Then $\omega$ is the sum of $(k-1)$-forms of the type
$$
fdx^1\wedge\dots\wedge\hat{dx^i}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^k,
$$
and it suffices to prove the theorem for each of these. Now Spivak claims the following (for the case $j=i$):
$$
\int_{[0,1]^{k-1}}{I^{k}_{(j,\alpha)}}^*(fdx^1\wedge\dots\wedge\hat{dx^i}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^k)
=\int_{[0,1]^k}f(x^1,\dots,\alpha,\dots,x^k)dx^1\dots dx^k.
$$
Now, I know that a couple of posts have already been made on this part of the proof, but those were not helpful to me, so I will proceed to clarify my own confusion.

${I^{k}_{(j,\alpha)}}^*(fdx^1\wedge\dots\wedge\hat{dx^i}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^k)=({I^{k}_{(j,\alpha)}}^*f)({I^{k}_{(j,\alpha)}}^*dx^1)\wedge...\wedge\hat{dx^i}\wedge...\wedge({I^{k}_{(j,\alpha)}}^*dx^k)$

${I^{k}_{(j,\alpha)}}^*f=f\circ{I^{k}_{(j,\alpha)}}=f(x^1,\dots,x^{j-1},\alpha,x^{j+1},\dots,x^k)$

So i can have $$
\int_{[0,1]^{k-1}}{I^{k}_{(j,\alpha)}}^*(fdx^1\wedge\dots\wedge\hat{dx^i}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^k)=\int_{[0,1]^{k-1}}f(x^1,\dots,x^{j-1},\alpha,x^{j+1},\dots,x^k)({I^{k}_{(j,\alpha)}}^*dx^1)\wedge...\wedge\hat{dx^i}\wedge...\wedge({I^{k}_{(j,\alpha)}}^*dx^k)$$

But how should I proceed further to get the equation? how do we go from $[0,1]^{k-1}$ to $[0,1]^k$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All he's doing is throwing in the extra $dx^i$ so that *all* the integrals over the faces of the cube are instead $k$-fold integrals over the entire cube. Why can he do this? Because $\int_0^1 dx^i = 1$ and we're integrating $f(x)$ with $x^i$ set equal to $\alpha$ (so that the function we're integrating is independent of $x^i$), the equality you copied follows. For example, $\int_{[0,1]} f(x,1)\,dx = \int_{[0,1]^2} f(x,1)\,dx\,dy$.

Comment: But before that i need to show$$(I^k_{j,\alpha}){}^*f dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{dx^j}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^k = f(x^1,\dots,x^{j-1},\alpha,x^{j+1},\dots,x^k)dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{dx^j}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^k.$$.  And  I have shown  $$(I^k_{j,\alpha}){}^*f dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{dx^j}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^k=f(x^1,\dots,x^{j-1},\alpha,x^{j+1},\dots,x^k)({I^{k}_{(j,\alpha)}}^*dx^1)\wedge...\wedge\hat{dx^i}\wedge...\wedge({I^{k}_{(j,\alpha)}}^*dx^k)$$  How should I go further?i mean How can I say $${I^{k}_{(j,\alpha)}}^*dx^1=dx^1$$ and so on

Comment: I did small typing error in second equation.in place of $j$ used $i$ and instead wide hat used small hat by mistake.

Comment: This whole thing is a notational mess. Look at the definition on p. 98. If $I=I^k_{j,\alpha}$, then $I^*dx^i = dx^i$ when $i<j$ and $I^*dx^i = dx^{i-1}$ when $i>j$. I suggest you write things out explicitly for $k=2$ and for $k=3$. (So I guess my answer should be modified: He's throwing in the integral $\int_0^1 dx^k = 1$, because all the indices have been shifted.)

Comment: By the way, judging from several of your posts, you might find my YouTube videos on differential forms and Stokes's Theorem (with lots of examples and applications) helpful. See the link in my profile. They are a lot more explicit and concrete than you'll find Spivak's text. That said, I do not discuss integration on cubes or chains.

Comment: In the above proof we used ${I^{k}_{(j,\alpha)}}^*f=f\circ{I^{k}_{(j,\alpha)}}=f(x^1,\dots,x^{j-1},\alpha,x^{j+1},\dots,x^k)$ But spivak defines $I^{k}_{(j,\alpha)}(x)=I^{k}(x^1,\dots,x^{j-1},\alpha,x^j,\dots,x^{k-1})=(x^1,\dots,x^{j-1},\alpha,x^j,\dots,x^{k-1})$ for $x \in [0,1]^{k-1}$ so accordingly this should be ${I^{k}_{(j,\alpha)}}^*f=f\circ{I^{k}_{(j,\alpha)}}=f(x^1,\dots,x^{j-1},\alpha,x^{j},\dots,x^{k-1})$

Comment: This is the notational mess I referred to three comments above.